# How to set dropdownlist in .aspx page from managed code via DOM

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, drop-down-menu

I've a control that sits in the *.aspx* page, but the dynamic code is in separate project in *Page.xaml.cs*.

On the same page as the control, I have:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownAppServer" runat="server" >
```

In the *Page.xaml.cs* I've tried doing this:

```
HtmlElement element = doc.GetElementById( "DropDownAppServer" );
element.SetAttribute( "option", "blah" );
```

Didn't work. Although it works with:

```
<input type="text" id="Text1" disabled="disabled" value="My Initial Value" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you elaborate as to why you are not doing

```
DropDownAppServer.Option = blah?
```

You can use **FindControl(ctrlName)** functions to get references to children objects if you don't have explicit access to the control.

Comment: I can't do DropDownAppServer.Option = blah?
because this is a silverlight control, that is being instantiated in the a separate project in a .aspx page. The drop down itself is in the .aspx page with that silverlight control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Silverlight, but coupling your controls together by name is very fragile.

Is there a reason why you cannot pass a reference to the drop down to your control?  Or even a reference to the page your control is on, which would allow you to use Page.FindControl(...).